# How to send an email to multiple recipients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I want to send an email to `@user.email` and `@business.manager.email`.

The business doesn't always have a manager.

Is there a short way to create an array of recipients with these 2 (possibly 1) email addresses?

```
recipients = [@user.email, @business.manager.email]
mail(from: "admin@spam.com", to: recipients, subject: "Spam")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an array with an email, and push a second one.

```
recipients = [@user.email]
recipients << @business.manager.email if @business.manager
```

This won't push the manager's email unless there is a manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can also:
`recipients = [@user.email, @business.manager.email].compact.reject(&:blank?)`

Comment: This will actually fail based on the OP's use case. Since a `Manager` might not always exist for a `Business`, if an email attempt is made for a business without a manager, attempting to do `@business.manager.email` will cause a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass` error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the array declaration to one line, you could do this:

```
[@user.email, @business.manager.try(:email)].compact
```

`try` for the email will return `nil` if a business doesn't have a manager. And `compact` removes `nil` values from the array.